# MPAndroidChart, Is it possible to disable highlight on tap without disabling onValueSelected?

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to hide/disable highlight after tapping on an entry on the chart while keeping tapping functionality on? In order to enable tapping entries on the chart and displaying a custom dialog, I had to set:

```
isHighlightPerTapEnabled = true
```

This works fine but after tapping, a yellow highlight (cross-hairs) is visible on the chart. I am using linedatasets to draw on the graph and i've tried toggling:

```
setDrawHighlightIndicators = false
```

but this doesn't work.

I'm currently using: v3.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, for each dataset you have on your chart:

```
        setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false)
        setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator(false)
```